# Change background color for cells with Null Value

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysqli

I am trying to simplify the following code; i have a table that is populated with data from database. I would need the cells with no value to be highlighted(background color: yellow). I have the following code but it seems that it is very tedious:

```
if ($record["ADASentToClient"]==NULL)
echo "<td style=background-color:#fee0e0><div class='TableHead' ><input type=text size=4 name=ADASentToClient value='$record[ADASentToClient]' /></div></td>";
else if ($record["ADASentToClient"])
echo "<td style=background-color:><div class='TableHead' ><input type=text size=4 name=ADASentToClient value='$record[ADASentToClient]' /></div></td>";
```

Is there any JQuery approach to this? I tried css

```
input[type="text"], textarea:empty {
background-color : yellow; }
```

But is doesn't work properly with input type=text

Comment: I added a simple solution for you, strictly CSS. The other answers are a bit overdone but whichever way you decide to go is cool with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close to what you might need.

```
<?php  
    $records = array(
        array('ADASentToClient' => null),
        array('ADASentToClient' => 'foo'),
        array('ADASentToClient' => 'bar'),
    );
?>
<html>
<style>
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow; 
}
</style>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<?php foreach($records as $record) { ?>
<td class="<?php if(!isset($record['ADASentToClient'])) { echo 'isNull'; } ?>">
    <div class="TableHead">
        <input type="text" size="4" name="ADASentToClient" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($record['ADASentToClient']); ?>" />
    </div>
</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.isNull').find('input[type="text"]').addClass('yellow');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="text"], textarea').each(highlightEmpty);
  $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('keyup input',highlightEmpty);
})
function highlightEmpty(){
  if($(this).val() == '')
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  else
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color : yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/><input type="text"/><input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/><input type="text"/><input type="text"/>
<textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css syntax you could use

https://jsfiddle.net/zLob82gm/

CSS

```
textarea:empty {background:yellow;}
input[value=""] {background:yellow;}
```

HTML

```
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text" value='' />
```